# Given the JavaScript code below, how can I trigger a Return key press, so the link saves automatically?

Tags: javascript, browser, bookmarklet

I'm trying the semi new read it later app Matter, and they just created this js code to use as a bookmarklet to save links to my Queue. The way it works is it will grab the URL, open a popup window, autocomplete the URL field and wait until you press the Save button.

Is there anyway to make it press the button, or the return key by itself, without user interaction? I think it has to be a one liner so it can be saved as a bookmark. Also it may need like a 1 second delay so it can get the URL, I'm not sure.

```
javascript:(()=>%7B(async(o)=>%7Blet e=window.document;await(async()=>new Promise((t)=>%7Bif(e.readyState==="complete")%7Breturn t(e.readyState)%7Dwindow.addEventListener("load",()=>t(e.readyState))%7D))();const origin="https://web.getmatter.com";window.addEventListener("message",(e)=>%7Bif(e.origin!==origin%7C%7Ce.data.type!=="ASK_PAGE_HTML")%7Breturn%7De.source.postMessage(%7Btype:"PAGE_HTML",payload:document.documentElement.outerHTML%7D,origin)%7D);window.open(%60$%7B origin %7D/bookmarklet/save?url=$%7BencodeURIComponent(o.location.href)%7D%60,"MATTER_SAVE","popup=1,width=500,height=250")%7D)(window)%7D)()
```

Thanks in advance.

I tried some ChatGPT answers but none of them worked :P

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to click a button, if you can get hold of the button element. How you do this depends on the structure of the website/app itself.

Getting an element is simplest if it has an `id` property, e.g. for a button with the id 'myButton':

```
const myButton = document.getElementById("myButton"); 
myButton.click();
```

As a one-liner:

```
const myButton = document.getElementById("myButton"); myButton.click();
```

Otherwise, you might be able to use a class. For example, to get the first button with the class 'aButton':

```
const firstButton = document.getElementsByClassName("aButton")[0]; 
firstButton.click();
```

Again, as a one-liner:
`

```
const firstButton = document.getElementsByClassName("aButton")[0]; firstButton.click();
```

Comment: How can I add that to the code I provided, I just add it to the end? Thanks